# Laravel problem with users which are disabled, still can log in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

Problem is simple, when user has in table column ````isBlocked``` value 1, cant login. But in my case stil can.
I hope so someone find problem which i dont see

`App\Middleware\ActiveUser.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator,Redirect,Response;
use Closure;

class ActiveUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check())
        {            
            if (auth()->user()->isBlocked == 1) 
            {
                auth()->logout();
        
                return response(view('expired'));
            }

        } 
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
....
'active_user' => \App\Http\Middleware\ActiveUser::class,
];
```

`web route`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['active_user']], function(){
    Route::get('user/{param1}&={param2}', 'AuthController@index')->name('login');
});
```

Comment: Does your code even get inside the `auth()->check()` condition? My suggestion would be do add some `dd()`'s and see in which condition is not satisfied. Other suggestion would be to clear your app & route cache

Comment: @zlatan you are right ````auth()->check()```` not work. I replace with ````$user = $request->user();```` and ````if (!$user || $user->isBlocked == 1)```` do something. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your condition:

```
if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->isBlocked == 1) {
    auth()->logout();
    // you can also abort that user from accessing web pages
    // App::abort(401);
    return response(view('expired'));

   
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```